# Add a JFreeChart in to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jfreechart

if i have a my Jpanel and a my JFreeChart. How can I add this Chart in to the JPanel?

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("XYGraph");
   series.add(1, 1);
   series.add(1, 2);
   series.add(2, 1);
   series.add(3, 9);
   series.add(4, 10);

// Add the series to your data set
   XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
   dataset.addSeries(series);

// Generate the graph
   JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
   "XY Chart", // Title
   "x-axis", // x-axis Label
   "y-axis", // y-axis Label
   dataset, // Dataset
   PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // Plot Orientation
   true, // Show Legend
   true, // Use tooltips
   false // Configure chart to generate URLs?
);
```

and now, how can i add chart in my JPanle?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From an old [java forums thread](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/16273-little-help-adding-jfreechart-graph-jpanel.html)

```
JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
 ..
ChartPanel CP = new ChartPanel(chart);
.. 
jPanel1.add(CP,BorderLayout.CENTER);
jPanel1.validate();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good tutorial to lead you further : [How to embed JFreeChart in JPanel](http://junaedhalim.blogspot.ca/2009/12/how-to-embed-jfreechart-in-jpanel.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Cos(x) and Cos^2(x) versus x", parent);
ChartPanel myChart = new ChartPanel(chart);
myChart.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
jPanel1.add(myChart,BorderLayout.CENTER);
jPanel1.validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but I was able to identify a way to solve this.

```html
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 102, 51));
  panel.setBounds(50, 64, 955, 888);
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
  panel.setLayout(null); //Absolute Layout

XYSeries series = new XYSeries("XY Chart");
  XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Testing Chart", "Date", "Average Profit", dataset);
  
  ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel((JFreeChart) null);
  chartPanelH2S.setChart(chart);
  chartPanelH2S.setBounds(39, 193, 419, 309);
  panel.add(chartPanel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Hope this helps